# find and set as variable and if

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, find, copy

I'm stucked with using Find and set as variable. I cannot get the result I need. In first sheet I have a column Test with values x or (x). If the value is x I need to copy the value from column EN. If the value is (x) do not copy.

the code copies values from column "EN" no matter x or (x)

I must have probably an error in using Set stfound

```
Dim ENcolumn
Dim xcolumn
Dim secrow
Dim lastrow
Dim totrow

Worksheets("List1").Activate
Worksheets("List1").Range("A1:C1").Find(What:="EN", MatchCase:=True, 
lookAT:=xlWhole).Activate
ENcolumn = ActiveCell.Column 'find and create variable

Worksheets("List1").Range("A1:C1").Find(What:="test", MatchCase:=True, 
lookAT:=xlWhole).Activate
xcolumn = ActiveCell.Column 'find and create variable

currow = ActiveCell.Row + 1 ''make one low rower than current row (first 
value)
lastrow = Worksheets("List1").Cells(Rows.Count, xcolumn).End(xlUp).Row
For totrow = currow To lastrow

Set stfound = Cells.Find(What:="x", After:=Cells(totrow, xcolumn), 
MatchCase:=True, lookAT:=xlWhole)

If Not stfound Is Nothing Then 'if value is found then do this

Worksheets("List1").Cells(totrow, ENcolumn).Copy 'copy values
Worksheets("List2").Activate
b = Worksheets("list2").Cells(Rows.Count, ENcolumn).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("list2").Cells(b + 1, 2).Select 'select first empty cell in 
second column
ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "receivercode"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "01.01.2019"
Worksheets("list1").Activate

End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False 'stop if false
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(1, 1).Select
MsgBox ("done")`
```

Now I get all the values from column "EN" copied to sheet2 to column2.

I need only those values in column EN that has x value in column 1

Comment: Hey there.  Welcome to SO.  I assume this is VBA.  Please add VBA tag to get better responses.

Comment: It might be easier to use a filter, instead of `Find` or the loop you have.

Comment: Set stfound = Range(Cells(totrow, xcolumn), Cells(totrow, xcolumn)).Find(What:="x", MatchCase:=True, lookAT:=xlWhole) 'try this instead of current string

Comment: Could you provide a better example of what you are trying to achieve here. Looking at the code, this can be done in a much lesser lines of code.

Comment: @Van Ng great, works nicely now. Thank you a lot.

Comment: That's good. And I have to assume that error was that searching was done in all cells of list, so everytime if there is any "x" cell on the list after current , function will return address of that cell. So code of checking was working no as mentioned

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I tried some variants like Set stfound = Range (totrow, xcolumn).Find(What:="x", MatchCase:=True, lookAT:=xlWhole) but did not help me to get the right result. Now I know that the range must be specified with cell both criteria. I will get on with my code. I will get back maybe because I'm rookie :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat search until you find all. Note that search is circular so you need to remember the first match. (The good news is that it can be any cell so you do not need to start searching from the very first cell.) Here is a frame for searching the entire sheet for a specific value:

```
Dim s1st As String
Dim rFnd as Range

Set rFnd = Nothing
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
     Set rFnd = .Cells.Find(What:="x", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _ 
                             SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
     If Not rFnd Is Nothing Then
       s1st = rFnd.Address
       Do
                ' do here what you need to do with your found cell. 
                ' rFnd points to the found cell with the value "x"
                ' e.g. 
           rFnd.Copy    ' single cell
           b = Worksheets("list2").Cells(Rows.Count, ENcolumn).End(xlUp).Row
           Worksheets("list2").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("list2").Cells(b + 1, 2)
           Set rFnd = .FindNext(rFnd)
       Loop While Not rFnd Is Nothing And rFnd.Address <> s1st
    End If
End With
```

NB: you may keep track of the actual destination cell instead of finding the last one in every loop. So you find the first destination cell (`.End(...)...`) once in the initialisation phase and then simply increment the row counter within the loop. Though you will notice any increase in speed only over thousands of rows.